# Unable to import python libraries to VScode venv

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I am running an Azure function locally in a venv inside of VS code. I try to get the file up and running but it repeats 'no module named Azure' - no problem. I attempt 'pip install azure' but I get the strangest out about requiring TLS/SSL.

```
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/azure/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/azure/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/azure/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/azure/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/azure
```

I have tried ' pip install --upgrade pip  --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org' but got the same error.

For reference the python version inside of the venv is 3.8.8 and I can easily import local modules outside of the venv. c

Comment: Where did your Python come from?  Python can be built with or without SSL support, and it looks like yours does not have it.  What operating system is this?

Comment: This is windows 10 and python came from just the standard python.org.

To create the venv I did, 'pip install venv'

Comment: Have you done `pip install ssl`?

Comment: This error message indicates that the `ssl` module is not available in your Python environment. As Tim Roberts said, `pip install ssl` can help.

Comment: It does not allow me to install ssl as that is part of the core library. Attempted to run a python script to see if anything was wrong and it now says no module found 'sklearn'  

  File "c:\Users\15126\OneDrive\diabetes_01.py", line 29, in <module>
    from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
PS C:\Users\15126\OneDrive\Csce5300\final_project> pip install sklearn
Requirement already satisfied: sklearn in c:\users\15126\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (0.0.post7)
PS C:\Users\15126\OneDrive\>

Comment: I did upgrade to python version 3.11.4 for a fresh install.

Comment: Two issues are the SSL module not being available in your Python environment and the inability to import the 'sklearn' library.    `.\venv\Scripts\activate` `pip install openssl-python`  `pip install certifi`  `pip install scikit-learn` . Hope this heps

Comment: [install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows%2Cportal%2Cv2%2Cbash&pivots=programming-language-csharp#install-the-azure-functions-core-tools) in text `azure-functions` . Install packages with pip in an Azure Function, you need to add the names and versions of the required packages to the requirements.txt file, and then install them by using pip. Here is an example command to install the packages from the requirements.txt file.
`pip install -r requirements.txt`
Make sure to replace requirements.txt with the name of your requirements file.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues are SSL module not being available in your Python environment and inability to import the `sklearn` library.

- To activate a virtual environment
  `.\venv\Scripts\activate`
- Install required packages.
  `pip install openssl-python`  `pip install certifi`  `pip install scikit-learn` `pip install openssl-python`.
- I Followed this [reference](https://pypi.org/project/azure/) to install azure.

  `pip install azure==4.0.0`

[image]

[image]

- Initially Install Azure Functions Core [Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows%2Cportal%2Cv2%2Cbash&pivots=programming-language-csharp#install-the-azure-functions-core-tools).
- If you want to install required packages in `requirements.txt`  which is in `azure-functions`, add the names of the pacakage and versions to the `requirements.txt` file and install by using pip.
- The command to install packages from the `requirements.txt` file is `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Comment: Thank you, I had a brain fart moment. 

I was able to uninstall/install VS code, python and Azure core functions tools. I got sci-kit learn installed and all is good. Not sure what fixed it out of the above but something did. Thank you.

Comment: Hi codingcloudcowboy, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)